# Making the count down timer skip 5 seconds when button is pressed (Android studios)

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer, seconds

I'm working on an Android application where I would like the CountdownTimer to skip 5 seconds when the reset button is pressed. For example, if the reset button is pressed when count down timer is at t = 15, the timer will skip the next five seconds and hence the timer will now display t = 10. Here's what I tried but it didn't work:

Button Code:

```
buttonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonReset);

    buttonReset.setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    TextView output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Display);
                    r = 1;
                    output.setText("");
                    resetStatus = true;
                }
            }
    );
```

**Edit:** I have updated the timer code. Now, I cancel the old timer and start a new one.
Count down timer code:

```
    public void start()
{
    new CountDownTimer(59*1000, 1000)
    {
        TextView timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Timer);
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            int TimeSeconds = (int) millisUntilFinished/1000;

            if (resetStatus)
            {
                cancel();

                TimeSeconds = TimeSeconds - 5;
                final int finalTimeSeconds = TimeSeconds;

                new CountDownTimer(finalTimeSeconds*1000, 1000)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        if (finalTimeSeconds >= 10)
                        {
                           //displays time
                            timer.setText("00:" + finalTimeSeconds);
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            //displays time
                            timer.setText("00:0" + finalTimeSeconds);
                        }
                        resetStatus = false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        gameOverDialogue();

                    }
                }.start();
            }

            else
            {
                if (TimeSeconds >= 10)
                {
                    //displays time
                    timer.setText("00:" + TimeSeconds);
                }

                else
                {
                    //displays time
                    timer.setText("00:0" + TimeSeconds);
                }

            }
        }
        public void onFinish()
        {
            gameOverDialogue();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

When I press the reset button now, the timer skips 5 seconds after which the display freezes. However, the timer keeps ticking and reaches 0. I think it's because in the second count down timer the `final` variable `finalTimeSeconds`is used instead of `TimeSeconds`. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only modify, one time, the time to display, but your CountDownTimer is not affected by this edit.

You should restart another CountDownTimer with the new delay and cancel the current one.

Comment: I have changed the code in my question. I cancel the old timer and start a new one now but another problem occurs which I have described at the bottom of the edited question

Comment: In your updated code, the second CountDownTimer that you create does not contains the same code as the first one. You had better to create your own subclass of CountDownTimer and create new of them when needed. The cancel shoud be done directly in your onclick, and then you start a new one with updated time. Forget about your boolean resetStatus.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your display changes with your flag, but the timer doesn't. Your assignment

```
int TimeSeconds = (int) millisUntilFinished/1000;
```

runs on every tick. You check the `resetStatus` flag and adjust the TextView, but that has no effect on the actual timer. The next time it ticks, it will have the proper (undeducted) time remaining.

Solving this problem can be kind of tricky. You can, as @MoraS suggested, create a new CountdownTimer each time a deduction is warranted. This solution will work, but if you expect deductions often, it may slow down the app a bit.

My suggestion would be to keep track of the total number of deductions, use that to keep the TextView up to date, and cancel the timer early as appropriate.

Comment: I have changed the code in my question. I cancel the old timer and start a new one now but another problem occurs which I have described at the bottom of the edited question

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. When you say timer are your referring to the CountDownTimer or the TextView timer? If you're talking about the CountDownTimer, how do you know that the timer is still ticking? If you're talking about the TextView, how can it be that your display freezes but the timer is still running?

Comment: The CountDownTimer() skips 5 secs and the Textview timer displays the deducted time. Now, the Textview timer freezes but the CountDownTimer() keeps counting down from the time after deduction if that makes sense. e.g, say CountDownTimer is at 55, if I press the reset button, the TextView timer displays 50 and freezes. However, the CountDowbTimer continues counting from 50 to 0

Comment: Take a look at @MoraS's comment. I think you follow Mora's instructions, you'll have much cleaner, more functional code and this issue will go away.